# Is there a builder based java api for selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

Does anyone know of a builder-based alternative/supplement to the "classical" [com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html) interface ? It just seems like it'd be a much better approach for this api...

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [Tellurium Automated Testing Framework](http://code.google.com/p/aost/)?

Comment: I'd prefer something selenium based. Have you tried cucumber ?

Comment: By "Selenium-based" you mean...? Looking at the Tellurium docs, it supports running tests through Selenium. I haven't tried Cucumber, but it looks very interesting. Right now I'm experimenting with PageObject pattern in my Selenium tests (http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/wiki/PageObjects)